# register role in elasticsearch through ansible

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, devops

I'm trying to create a new security role.

This method works, because it's plain `cURL` call:

```
curl -X POST -u tajikistan:himalaya "192.168.2.13:9200/_security/role/dolboed_suka?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [ "*" ],
      "privileges": ["create", "index", "read", "read_cross_cluster", "view_index_metadata", "write", "create_index"]
    }
  ]
}
'
```

However, if I try to do this through the ansible `uri` module like this

```
name: create role 
  uri:
    url: '192.168.2.13:9200/_security/role/dolboed_suka?pretty'
    method: POST
    body:
      {"indices":[{"names":["*"],"privileges":["create","index","read","read_cross_cluster","view_index_metadata","write","create_index"]}]}
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: 'application/json'
    url_username: tajikistan
    url_password: himalaya
  register: result
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: [elasticsearch-db-02]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "content": "", "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error unknown url type: 192.168.2.14>","redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "192.168.2.14:9200/_security/role/doldoeb_suka?pretty"}
```

Comment: You need a scheme in front of your url => `http(s)://....`. You might also need to [force basic authentification](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-force_basic_auth)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error, you can see the following message:

```
"msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error unknown url type: 192.168.2.14>"
```

You should add a scheme to your URL, I mean, use `http://192.168.2.13:9200...` instead of just `192.168.2.13:9200`:

```
name: create role 
  uri: 
    url: 'http://192.168.2.13:9200/_security/role/dolboed_suka?pretty'
    method: POST
    body: {"indices":[{"names":["*"],"privileges":["create","index","read","read_cross_cluster","view_index_metadata","write","create_index"]}]}
    body_format: json
    headers:
      - Content-Type: 'application/json'
   url_username: tajikistan
   url_password: himalaya
 register: result
```

Comment: Hello Joom187. I suggest you have a look at this article about how to react to answers in StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Follow the guidelines so we can keep StackOverflow being the great community that it is now.